Actualizar un valor de mi registro despues de insertarlo - php y mysql
¿Cómo puedo actualizar un valor de mi base de datos, enseguida de hacer una inserción?
Intente este código pero no actualiza y ya revisé si es que entro al if de la inserción, pero no hace la actualización.
$cliente= "INSERT INTO mttoPreventivo (Id_preventivo, fecha, hora, folio, contrato, cliente , responsable, direccion,
     contacto, modelo, serie, ubicacion, marca, power, LED, cableAlimentacion, puerto, cablePaciente, nuevoPaciente,
     mantenimiento, exportar, eliminar, actualizaEvento, fechaHora, actualizaMonitor, apagar, demo, idiomas,
     cablePaciente2, cableAlimentacion2, acdc, correctivo, fechaPreventivo, modeloS, serieS, Tequipo, marcaS, observaciones)

    VALUES ( 0, '$fecha', '$hora', '$iniciales', '$contrato', '$cliente', '$responsable', '$direccion', '$contacto',
    '$modelo', '$serie', '$ubicacion', '$marca', '$power', '$LED', '$cableAlimentacion',' $puerto', '$cablePaciente', 
    '$nuevoPaciente', '$mantenimiento', '$exportar', '$eliminar', '$actualizaEvento', '$fechaHora', '$actualizaMonitor',
    '$apagar', '$demo', '$idiomas', '$cablePaciente2', '$cableAlimentacion2', '$acdc', '$correctivo', '$fechaPreventivo',
    '$modeloS', '$serieS', '$Tequipo', '$marcaS', '$observaciones')";


    if (mysqli_query($con, $cliente)) {
        //$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password) ;
        //mysqli_select_db($conn, $database) or die ("Error al conectar a la base de datos".mysql_error());
        $sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM mttoPreventivo  WHERE folio='$iniciales' ");
        $extraido= mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql);
        $folio2=$iniciales.$extraido['Id_preventivo'];
        print_r($folio2);
        $sql2= "UPDATE mttoPreventivo SET folio='$folio2' WHERE Id_preventivo='1'";
        /*echo "<script>
                alert('Se almaceno la información correctamente.');
                window.location= 'reportePreventivo.php? variable1=$vendedor&variable2=$puesto&variable3=$correo&variable4=$tel'
            </script>";*/
    //header("Location: reporteFallas.php? variable1=$nombre_vendedor&variable2=$puesto&variable3=$correo&variable4=$tel");
    //print('Se almaceno la información correctamente. Actualice la pagina para seguir reportando fallas');
    } else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
    
    }

    mysqli_close($con);


Con un UPDATE ? Por que estás haciendo un update dentro del mismo proceso de un insert ?

Si, primero hago el insert y después el update, para modificar un valor, eso se puede?

De que se puede se puede, pero al igual que ejecutas el insert, debes ejecutar el update.

Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla!

Roberto, te sirvió mi respuesta o no ?

Primero que nada aprendamos a dar buenos nombres a las variables. Trata de que no sean $sql1, $sql2, no... si es un update, di que es un update y de que.
Segundo, estás haciendo la query SQL para el UPDATE, pero no hay ejecución de la misma, solo hay un montón de texto comentado.
$updateFolio = "UPDATE mttoPreventivo SET folio='$folio2' WHERE Id_preventivo='1'";
    //...Texto comentado
}

Debes agregar el mysql_query luego de la consulta para ejecutarla
if (mysqli_query($con, $updateFolio)) {
    echo "El registro fue actualizado correctamente.";
} else {
    echo "Error al ejecutar la consulta: " . mysqli_error($con) . " // CONSULTA: " . $updateFolio;
}

Tercero, y como lo comenté antes, separa los procesos de INSERT y UPDATE. Esto es para evitar tener tanto código en spaghetti como dicen.
Si quieres realizar un INSERT, que el proceso sea solo eso. Si luego quieres hacer un UPDATE mismo caso.
Pero de nuevo, no entiendo por que solo quieres hacer un update a un dato en específico.

Acá la modificación al código, para optimizar el proceso de insert + idgenerado.
Con este código, al menos nos estamos ahorrando 1 consulta hacia la base de datos, al obtener de manera automática el ID Generado.
//Paso1: Realizar el insert del cliente (me ahorro el código de la query para el ejemplo)
$insertCliente = "[...]";
//Paso2: Ejecutar el insert
if (mysqli_query($con, $cliente)) {
    //Paso3: Obtener el id generado automáticamente (puedes mostrarlo para comprobar de ser necesario)
    $idGenerado= mysqli_insert_id($con);
    if ($IdGenerado) {
        //Paso4: Concatenar el texto con el ID
        $folioGenerado = "RMMPREVENT" . $IdGenerado;
        //Paso5: Hacer el update para el folio
        $updateFolio = "UPDATE mttoPreventivo SET folio='$folioGenerado' WHERE Id_preventivo='$IdGenerado'";
        //Paso6: Ejecutar el update
        if (mysqli_query($con, $updateFolio)) {
            echo "Folio actualizado correctamente: $folioGenerado";
        } else {
            echo "Error al actualizar el folio: " . folioGenerado . " con error: " . mysqli_error($con);
        }
    } else {
        echo "Error al obtener el ID generado automáticamente.";
    }
} else {
    echo "Error al insertar el registro: " . mysqli_error($con);
}
mysqli_close($con);


cuando genero el reporte debo asignar un folio, entonces antepongo una cadena de texto que quiero unir con mi ad generado por la base de datos, por ejemplo el folio empieza con la palabra RMMPREVENT Y LO QUIERO CONCATENAR CON EL ID QUE SE GENERA DE MI BASE DE DATOS quedando asi por ejemplo:

la primera vez RMMPREVENT1, LUEGO RMMPREVENT2 Y SUCESIVAMENTE

entonces segun yo para poder hacer eso y tener el id que genere en la inserción a mi base de datos primero guardo en el folio la palabra RMMPREVENT Y DESPUES la la quiero modificar concatenandola con el id

Ok, pero no es necesario hacerlo en ese orden. Puedes, solamente hacer el insert, y antes de insertar, consultar el ID anterior, y sumarle 1, entonces ahí formar tu codigo, y guardarlo. Asi no tener que ejecutar 3 consultas (insert, select, update), y solo ejecutar 2 (select, insert)

Mismo caso, puedes simplemente rescatar el ID luego del insert, sin hacer el select como tal.

@robertomedrano hay  tantas malas practicas ahi que no se por donde empezar.. para empezar, aunque excorpion no lo dijo, debe estar todo en transacciones!!!!! que pasa si falla un insert? que pasa si falla un update? que pasa si hay 2 usuarios al mismo tiempo haciendo lo mismo???

Haré una sugerencia para optimizar el proceso de insert + generación del ID para el folio, y ahorrarnos el SELECT. Pero como dice bianchi, falta un buen montón de cosas.

y porque, en tu sano juicio, querrias hacer algo como lo que estas preguntando y agregando todo ese texto a un campo? si el valor ya esta en la tabla, porque querrias concatenarlo en la DB? si es por como lo mostras en la pantalla, la respuesta es que esta mal ;) @robertomedrano

Yo por ahora asumiré que quiere el código por alguna razón... más allá, a esperar respuesta jaja
